# Invoking SSIS 2012 packages in SSIS catalog from JDBC

Tags: jdbc, ssis

I have a set of SSIS packages deployed to the SSIS catalog. There's a custom stored procedure that wraps the catalog.create_execution and catalog.start_execution procs to invoke packages with specific parameters and settings.

When I call the wrapper stored procedure to run a package using a Microsoft client it works as expected, the package runs and return values from the proc work. However, when I attempt to invoke the procedure from a JDBC client, the call is aborted right at the execution of the catalog procs.

A trace of the jdbc side of this interaction seems to indicate the query was canceled, but there's nothing issuing a cancel on the caller side. In the same environment many other stored procedures do work from jdbc correctly and this unexpected abort happens only when the SSIS catalog procedures are present.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior?

Note that there is also some Windows vs SQL Authentication in play here, using EXECUTE AS, to allow the JDBC connection - which can't use Windows auth - to connect and execute the wrapper proc.

Comment: Does it ever get to `start_execution`? Running synchronous mode and maybe the jdbc query is set to default timeout at 30 or 60 seconds?